# Why is the second ifelse not evaluated?

Tags: r, if-statement

In the code below, I do not understand why the second `ifelse()` is not evaluated. Can someone explain it? How to rewrite the `ifelse` statement?

The `y1==1` and `y2==1` in the last row are matched, and the column result should be filled with `1`.

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(0,0,NA,NA,NA),y1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1),x2=c(0,NA,NA,0,NA),
                 y2=c(1,NA,NA,NA,1))

df$result <- with(df, ifelse((x1==0 & x2==0), 0, ifelse((y1==1 & y2==1), 1, 100)))
```

Comment: `NA` is neither true nor false. The condition  `x1==0 & x2==0` returns `T NA NA NA`, in this case the `ifelse` will return `NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df$result <- with(df, ifelse((x1==0 & x2==0) & !is.na(x1==0 & x2==0), 0,
                             ifelse((y1==1 & y2==1), 1, 100)))
```

Result:

```
> df
  x1 y1 x2 y2 result
1  0 NA  0  1      0
2  0 NA NA NA     NA
3 NA NA NA NA     NA
4 NA NA  0 NA     NA
5 NA  1 NA  1      1
```

**Solution using `apply()` and `if()`**

If you want to use `if()` and `apply()` instead of `ifelse()` do:

```
df$result = apply(df,1,function(x){

    if(is.na(x["x1"]==0 & x["x2"]==0) & is.na(x["y1"]==1 & x["y2"]==1)){
        return(NA)
    }

    if(!is.na(x["x1"]==0 & x["x2"]==0) & (x["x1"]==0 & x["x2"]==0)){
        return(0)
    }else if(!is.na(x["y1"]==1 & x["y2"]==1) & (x["y1"]==1 & x["y2"]==1)){
        return(1)
    }else{
        return(100)
    }

})
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: oh, yes, you right. I overlooked that. Could you please also supply solution  with if() statement? I could not figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: `if()` is not vectorized as `ifelse` but the logic conditions should be the same.

Comment: yes, I know that it is not vectorised, this is why I find it problematic to apply the if() statement, in particular involving 4 columns. I wonder how this would be done, any clue? I understand that one of the `apply` function must be applied but how?

Answer (score 2):

We can try with `pmax` and `rowSums`

```
df$result <- pmax(+(!!rowSums(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)])), 
          +(!!rowSums(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])), na.rm = TRUE)
df$result
#[1]  0 NA NA NA  1
```

Comment: very innovative and interesting answer, thank you. I'm also looking for if() statement solution, would you be able/willing to show how to do it? It involves 4 columns and if() is not vectorized, I'm very curious how this can be done. Many thanks!

Comment: @Maximilian  It involves looping through each row in a `for` loop and use the `if/else`

Comment: Oh, ok so I was right in thinking this is the only way. I thought there is better way other than looping. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Maximilian  `if/else` is not vectorized, so it can take only a single element at a time, while `ifelse` is vectorized.  Do you want a `for` loop solution?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot evaluate `NA`s. Notice that `(x1==0 & x2==0)` is `TRUE, NA, NA, NA`
So `ifelse(  (df$x1==0 & df$x2==0), 0,  "Something)` is `0, NA, NA, NA`

I would suggest the following

```
library(dplyr)
df$result <- case_when(df$x1==0 & df$x2==0 & !is.na(df$x1) & !is.na(df$x2) ~ 0,
                   df$y1==1 & df$y2==1 ~ 1,
                   TRUE ~ 100))
```

Comment: `case_when` I suspect is a `dplyr` function, am I right? This should be stated in your answer if this is so. Thanks.